# SELECT DISTINCT returning duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

My mysql code is returning duplicate values when I use the code below:

Firstly, here's my code:

```
$customer = htmlspecialchars($_GET['customer']);

$STH = $DBH->query( "SELECT DISTINCT customer FROM table WHERE customer LIKE
    '$customer%' LIMIT 4" );
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while( $row = $STH->fetch() ){
    $customer_name = $row['customer'];
    $list .= "<p>" .$customer_name. "</p>";

    echo $list;
}
```

Is there something wrong with my SELECT statement?

I read that duplicate values can be returned when there are subtle differences in the data entries like spaces, etc. I have checked and rechecked the entries and they are exactly the same throughout.

Comment: You wrong starts when you're passing `$customer` directly to query

Comment: seeing what is being returned might help...

Comment: Can you run the same query in phpMyAdmin or something equivalent and check you are getting the result expected?

Comment: please post your result

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I've tried passing it like '" .$customer. "%' and it still returns duplicates

Comment: Not quite possible, unless you have spaces or invisible characters in the customer's name. `DISTINCT something` will always return distinct something...

Comment: Are you sure that `customer` doesn't have any white space, and that they're actually different?

Comment: @LatheesanKanes, running it in phpMyAdmin does give me the desired result

Comment: @h2ooooooo, yes, I have checked and checked and checked again

Comment: @proPhet Just to make sure - what does `SELECT customer, HEX(customer) FROM table WHERE customer LIKE '$customer%' GROUP BY customer LIMIT 4` output? If the hex values are different it's because of invisible characters.

Comment: You probably should reset $list with empty string and/or echo $list outside the cycle.

Comment: @h2ooooooo, the HEX values are identical

Comment: @alexius, I echoed the list outside the while loop and it's working fine now! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending to `$list` every iteration, then echoing out the whole thing each time.  So if the query returns Person1, Person2, and Person3, this will be your output:

```
Person1    # End of loop iteration 1
Person1
Person2    # End of loop iteration 2
Person1
Person2
Person3    # End of loop iteration 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$customer = htmlspecialchars($_GET['customer']);

$STH = $DBH->query( "SELECT DISTINCT customer FROM table WHERE customer LIKE
    '$customer%' LIMIT 4" );
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while( $row = $STH->fetch() ){
    $customer_name = $row['customer'];
    $list .= "<p>" .$customer_name. "</p>";
}
echo $list;
```

You are echo list in each cycle. I think this is the case.